# How to get the nearest date match in PHP from a SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently trying to get the nearest match of 2 sets of dates (d-m-Y) against a SQL database and then out put the matched InterestRate column name.

I have an example of my current code, this is mostly pseudo code and trying a few things out. If that helps.

```
//$XSS_BLOCK2 = "05-05-2016";
$XSS_BLOCK3 = "20-05-2016"; //By the way The '2016-05-20' is user input so it will not be '2016-05-20' all the time, so it could be anything '2014-08-15'.
$today = date('d-m-Y');
$interest = 0;
$securesqlstring = $secureconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM LatePaymentRates");
$securesqlstring->execute();
while($row=$securesqlstring->fetch())
  {
     echo $row['StartDate'];
     echo $row['EndDate'];
     echo $row['InterestRate'];

    $varsin = array($XSS_BLOCK3, $today);
    $DateRange = new DateTime($varsin);
    $databasein = array($row['StartDate'], $row['EndDate']);
    $DateRanges = new DateTime($databasein);
    if(($DateRange >= $DateRanges) && ($DateRange >= $DateRanges)) {

      $dayrate = $row['InterestRate'] * $XSS_BLOCK3 / 36500;


    $start_date = new DateTime($DateRange);
    $end_date = new DateTime($DateRanges);
    $dd = date_diff($end_date, $start_date) * $dayrate;
    $interest += $dayrate;
    }

  }
  $LatePaymentInterest = $interest;
if (!$securesqlstring) // If there is an error it will show this message.
  {exit("Error in the SQL");}
```

Comment: What is the problem or error that you are finding?

Comment: Define 'nearest match'

Comment: Also, remember that your database has time on it. That influences range searches because a datetime with only date is only equal to its date and 00:00:00. Ex.: 14-05-2016 != 14-05-2016 01:02:03

Comment: So if the 2 php input date Vars both match the year or the month of the database --> get the InterestRate Var.

Comment: I am currently porting the code from C# i can drop the code for that if that helps with the logic, with the debug outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do we really need to spell this one out? I feel like I must be missing something...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE '2016-05-20' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate;
```

Comment: By the way The '2016-05-20' is user input so it will not be '2016-05-20' all the time, so it could be anything '2014-08-15'.

Comment: @Mattlinux1 Well fancy that.

Comment: Furthermore the query would need to take into account the month having some movement between dates, as you can tell i'm currently not familiar with SQL.

Comment: I'll take the query as the answer, because i can re code / strip the date then with year or months. best regards.