# How to convert a SQL query into a prepared statement PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently stuck in converting the below SQL Query into a prepared statement.

```
$XSS_BLOCK2 = "22-07-2004";
$XSS_BLOCK3 = "20-05-2016";
$dateswitch1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($XSS_BLOCK2));
$dateswitch2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($XSS_BLOCK3));

$securesqlstring = $secureconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Lateday WHERE $dateswitch1 AND $dateswitch2 BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate");
```

E.g. working code `$securesqlstring = $secureconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Lateday WHERE '2004-07-22' AND '2016-05-20' BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate");`

Code Example:

```
$XSS_BLOCK2 = "22-07-2004";
$XSS_BLOCK3 = "20-05-2016";
$dateswitch1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($XSS_BLOCK2));
$dateswitch2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($XSS_BLOCK3));
$securesqlstring = $secureconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Lateday WHERE ? AND ? BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate");
$securesqlstring->bindParam(1,$dateswitch1);
$securesqlstring->bindParam(2,$dateswitch2);
$securesqlstring->execute();
```

Currently not working.

Example of working update statement that worked on another project I want to convert the SQL Query above to something like the example below:

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$stocklevel = $_POST["stocklevel"];

$XSS_Block1 = htmlentities ($id, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$XSS_Block2 = htmlentities ($stocklevel, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=;","","");
$mattssqlstring = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `products` SET stocklevel=stocklevel-? WHERE ID=? and stocklevel = ?");
$mattssqlstring->bindParam(1,$XSS_Block2);
$mattssqlstring->bindParam(2,$XSS_Block1);
$mattssqlstring->bindParam(3,$XSS_Block2);
$mattssqlstring->execute();
```

Comment: To begin with `WHERE $dateswitch1` makes no sense. Did you mean something like `WHERE $dateswitch1 IS NOT NULL` or something?

Comment: It works by checking to get the best date match within the database, it currently works by checking the two dates with two date values within the database. for infomation it can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226254/how-to-get-the-nearest-date-match-in-php-from-a-sql-database

Comment: What error or other symptoms do you get? "not working" is not a very helpful description of the problem.

Comment: It wont select anything at all but works with, $securesqlstring = $secureconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Lateday WHERE '22-07-2004' AND '20-05-2016' BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate");

Comment: The linked question has a query like : `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE '2016-05-20' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate;` with no `AND` before the `BETWEEN`. That's different to this one.

Comment: Furthermore echo $dateswitch1; output is correct 22-07-2004
echo $dateswitch2; output is correct 20-05-2016

Comment: Are you using emulated prepares? If not MySQL may be struggling to determine what the bind type is since you're not associating `$dateswitch1` to a field.

Comment: 2 seconds I'll add an example of how i normally do it with a prepared statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$XSS_BLOCK2 = "22-07-2004";
$XSS_BLOCK3 = "20-05-2016";
$securesqlstring = $secureconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Lateday` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(:date1,'%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(:date2,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN `StartDate` AND `EndDate`");
$mattssqlstring->bindParam(':date1',$XSS_BLOCK2);
$mattssqlstring->bindParam(':date2',$XSS_BLOCK3);
$securesqlstring->execute();
```

Comment: Check out this sql fiddle although i think that you have changed your query already, i think you need to change it to the last select example in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/915c1/9

Comment: If i understood right you want results for those two specific dates ($XSS_block2 and 3) to be inside the date-range specified by `startdate` and `enddate` fields

Comment: The database values are set to Y-m-d so i had to use $dateswitch1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($XSS_BLOCK2));
$dateswitch2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($XSS_BLOCK3));

Comment: So i changed the values to $dateswitch1 & $dateswitch2

Comment: Also i miss typed $mattssqlstring it should be $securesqlstring it now works.

Comment: @Mattlinux1 great regarding the prepared statement part. Check the select queries in the fiddle, i don't know the exact schema of your table but I really don't think you should use the syntax provided in your example. If those two dates are inside `startdate` and `enddate` each one of them you should have at least 2 results. Running your query in the fiddle provided 0 results.

Comment: I had a conundrum the other day, trying to find a fix, so i asked a question on here. The query works fine my end for what i need, if you think you can solve the problem or have a better fix please feel free to post it on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226254/how-to-get-the-nearest-date-match-in-php-from-a-sql-database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112134/discussion-between-peter-darmis-and-mattlinux1).